# Массовое перенаправление в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Сайт имеет подобные адреса страниц:

```
http://www.site.ru/яблоки/челябинск/
http://www.site.ru/яблоки/краснодар/
http://www.site.ru/яблоки/москва/
```

и так далее.
То есть, яблоки в каждом городе.

Теперь яблок больше нет, но есть груши. И яблоки нужно заменить на груши.

Как правильно прописать в `.htaccess` условие, чтобы массово перенаправить страницы с `/яблоки/город/` на `/груши/город/`?

Answer (score 1):

честно сказать, не знаю работает ли htaccess с кириллицей, примерно так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^yabloki/([a-z]+)/{0,1}$ file.php?fruit=pear&city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

GET параметры, которые принимает скрипт, под себя перепишите

вообще правильнее сравнивать входные параметры и заменять яблоки на груши в скрипте-обработчике

Comment: Подозреваю, что автор вопроса хотел 301 редирект браузера с яблок на груши ;)